# Entities relationship only return ID with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, crud

I'm working on my 1st Symfony project with CRUD and entities.

I've generated all my entities (with all getters and setters necessary) but something's going wrong.
Actually, my entity PjTickets is linked to my other entity, PjCompany.

PjTripsshould also return datas for the PjCompany (on the foreign key).
Actually, PjTripsreturns all the fields of PjCompany but null (except the id one).

Here is my PjTrips(Entity/PjTrips.php) :

```
<?php

namespace VoyagesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * PjTrips
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pj_trips", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_departure", columns={"departure"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_arrival", columns={"arrival"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_companyID", columns={"company"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PjTrips
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="quantity", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float", precision=10, scale=0, nullable=false)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var \PjAirports
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PjAirports")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="arrival", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * })
     */
    private $arrival;

    /**
     * @var \PjCompany
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PjCompany")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="company", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * })
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @var \PjAirports
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PjAirports")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="departure", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * })
     */
    private $departure;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return PjTrips
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    /**
     * Set quantity
     *
     * @param integer $quantity
     *
     * @return PjTrips
     */
    public function setQuantity($quantity)
    {
        $this->quantity = $quantity;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get quantity
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getQuantity()
    {
        return $this->quantity;
    }

    /**
     * Set price
     *
     * @param float $price
     *
     * @return PjTrips
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get price
     *
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * Set arrival
     *
     * @param \VoyagesBundle\Entity\PjAirports $arrival
     *
     * @return PjTrips
     */
    public function setArrival(\VoyagesBundle\Entity\PjAirports $arrival = null)
    {
        $this->arrival = $arrival;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get arrival
     *
     * @return \VoyagesBundle\Entity\PjAirports
     */
    public function getArrival()
    {
        return $this->arrival;
    }

    /**
     * Set company
     *
     * @param \VoyagesBundle\Entity\PjCompany $company
     *
     * @return PjTrips
     */
    public function setCompany(\VoyagesBundle\Entity\PjCompany $company = null)
    {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get company
     *
     * @return \VoyagesBundle\Entity\PjCompany
     */
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    /**
     * Set departure
     *
     * @param \VoyagesBundle\Entity\PjAirports $departure
     *
     * @return PjTrips
     */
    public function setDeparture(\VoyagesBundle\Entity\PjAirports $departure = null)
    {
        $this->departure = $departure;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get departure
     *
     * @return \VoyagesBundle\Entity\PjAirports
     */
    public function getDeparture()
    {
        return $this->departure;
    }
}
```

Here is my PjCompany entity (Entity/PjCompany.php) :

```
namespace VoyagesBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * PjCompany
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pj_company")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PjCompany
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="label", type="string", length=250, nullable=false)
     */
    private $label;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set label
     *
     * @param string $label
     *
     * @return PjCompany
     */
    public function setLabel($label)
    {
        $this->label = $label;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get label
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return $this->label;
    }
}
```

And here is what a PjTrips find() request returns :

```
0 => PjTrips {#726 ▼
    -id: 1
    -date: DateTime @1574071200 {#728 ▶}
    -quantity: 165
    -price: 89.0
    -arrival: PjAirports {#710 ▼
      +__isInitialized__: false
      -id: 5
      -label: null
      -iata: null
       …2
    }
    -company: PjCompany {#662 ▶}
    -departure: PjAirports {#653 ▶}
  }
```

Any idea why I can't get any data for PjAirports.label and PjAirports.iata ?

Answer (score 0):

It is doctrine lazy loading. In this case when you get `PjTrips` entity some of your relation do not load from the DB immediately. Doctrine will set `PjCompany Proxy Object` which contains only ID, instead of `PjCompany Entity`, which contains all data. Only when you call, for example, `$trips->getArrival()->getLabel();` doctrine will load PjCompany entity from the DB. 
You can read more about this [here](https://www.uvdesk.com/en/blog/doctrine-proxy-objects-lazy-loading/) and [here](http://developer.happyr.com/choose-owning-side-in-onetoone-relation)